# EntityExtraction using AlchmenyAPI not returning any result

Tags: java, json, alchemyapi

I am using the AlchemyAPI for EntityExtraction-
 http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities?outputMode=json&text=<--tweet-->&apikey=<--apikey-->

I am encoding the text before passing it to the AlchemyAPI but in the json output, entities [] is empty.

I dont understand what could possibly be going wrong.

Thanks,
Sakshi

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the text itself

```
$.ajax({url:'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities',                    
        data    :   { text : selected_text,
              apikey : alchemyApiKey,
              outputMode : "json"},
         success :  function(response){var entities = response.entities;}
            });
```